# GridView Column click export data into Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm new to the ASP.NET world and need some help.

I need to create a GridView which shows the Employee's name. When a user clicks on the Employee Name, it will call the stored procedure to get particular details from the database and export the data into an excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

There are commercial and open sources libraries available to facilitate this task, but I am a fan of [DoddleReport](http://doddlereport.codeplex.com/) as it is easy to configure and use.

I wrote a [blog post](http://www.woodcp.com/2012/02/petapoco-doddlereport-dynamic-pivot-query/) demonstrating how to use DoddleReport and PetaPoco to export a SQL Server PIVOT query from an ASP.NET MVC3 application to Excel. The Excel portion of the task is only a couple lines of code.

The sample project is available on [github](https://github.com/tawman/PetaPocoPivot)